# TypeScript: Typing generic interface's method parameter by reading a value from the generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to define a generic interface which is able to handle any `Data` type. The interface has a `dataKey` property and its value is simply a `keyof Data`. It also has a handler function, and its parameter type should be the same type as the type of using `dataKey` to read a value from `Data`. Is should be something like this, but this does not work as  `Data[dataKey]` is not valid TypeScript:

```
interface Handler<Data> {
    dataKey: keyof Data,
    handler: (value: Data[dataKey]) => void
}
```

Is there a way to make it work? I could use `any` type instead of `Data[dataKey]`, but that doesn't make it type safe.

Here is an example how I would like to use the `Handler` interface:

```
function handleData<Data extends object>(data: Data, handler: Handler<Data>) {
    const value = data[handler.dataKey];
    handler.handler(value);
}

interface Person {
    name: string,
    age: number,
}

const person: Person = {name: "Seppo", age: 56};
const handler: Handler<Person> = {dataKey: "name", handler: (value: string) => {
    // Here we know that the type of `value` is string,
    // as it is the type of reading `name` from the person object.
    // If I change dataKey to "age", the type of `value`
    // should be `number`, respectively
    console.log("Name:", value);
}}

handleData(person, handler);
```

Comment: `interface Handler<Data, K extends keyof Data = keyof Data> {` - Then use `Data[K]` in your handler.

Comment: You can't really do this with an *interface* directly, but you can make a union type that works this way.  [Does this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wE4G2W) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: @caTS I tried your example but unfortunately I could not make it work. Could you show me a working example?

Comment: @jcalz Your example seems to work but I don't understand much of it :D

Comment: I will explain if I write up an answer; does "seems to work" mean it's good enough for your purposes? Do you need to test something before you can decide?

Comment: @jcalz I tested your solution in my application code and it works just as I wanted. :) So, feel free to write an answer / explanation if you wish. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Handler<Person>` to evaluate to a type that enforces the correlation between the `dataKey` property and the `handler` callback parameter type, you pretty much need it to be a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) with one member for eavery property of `Person`.  It would need to look like this:

```
interface Person {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}

type PersonHandler = Handler<Person>;
/* type PersonHandler = {
    dataKey: "name";
    handler: (value: string) => void;
} | {
    dataKey: "age";
    handler: (value: number) => void;
} */
```

That way a `Handler<Person>` would either be a value of type `{dataKey: "name", handler: (value: string) => void`, or it would be a value of type `{dataKey: "age", handler: (value: number) => void`.

So we are looking for a way to define `type Handler<T extends object> = ...` so that it generates the appropriate union type.  (Note that `interface`s cannot be union types, so I've changed `Handler` from an interface to a type alias.)

---

Here's one way to do it:

```
type Handler<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: {
  dataKey: K,
  handler: (value: T[K]) => void
} }[keyof T]
```

This is what's known as a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  A distributive object type is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which is immediately [indexed into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a union of its property types.  You can verify that if you have a union of keys `type K = K1 | K2 | K3 | ... | KN`, then the distributive object type `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]` evaluates to `F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3> | ... | F<KN>`.

In the above `Handler<T>` definition, we iterate over the keys of `T` (using the `-?` [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to remove any possible optionality from the properties, to suppress unwanted `undefined` types floating around in the output), and for each key `K`, we compute the corresponding `dataKey`/`handler` pair.  And then we index into it with the same set of keys, to get the union of all such values.

With that definition, `Handler<Person>` is the desired type:

```
type PersonHandler = Handler<Person>;
/* type PersonHandler = {
    dataKey: "name";
    handler: (value: string) => void;
} | {
    dataKey: "age";
    handler: (value: number) => void;
} */
```

And then the assignment also works as desired:

```
const handler: Handler<Person> = {
  dataKey: "name", handler: value => {
    console.log("Name:", value.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

Note that you don't have to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) that `value` is a `string`.  The compiler is able to infer [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) that `value` must be `string` because `Handler<Person>` is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), and the discriminant `dataKey` is `"name"`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsICcA8AVAfFAXigG8oBtAaSgEsEoBrCEAewDMpsBdAWgH4AuEgFgAUFChI4wOBSaCKAGlHiAFolQZBACgBucFAFcIg7JU4BKQvh3NqSUQF8oDsoxbsuo0awMIAxsDUzHRqyGgAIlJwOFAQAB7AEMgAzlDMAEYAVhABuFqS0iYKUKEa6ILwYRg4uJbEylB+wcnAUHqG0EQFcGSlaOgAdN2yIJwA3A19GANT6Lr6RuYTIg5eIrSJ6KxwftAAChjJwcJiUAhwALbGUC3otADmSqdw99cIBhfpGE+rIqKgkCgB3QRwQlTKhFg6n6mGBoNwywA9AAqKAA-aHYLg-qQ+qncTDORQABE5yuxOW4lU0M0UHmHUEtwelgI1lsSGWTgAPicqRIoiNBMSXhAKQ1qVVynT2kZBO9PhgWWy7JyoMjEWsmggWlBICDgoI4cciKQyddiQBlCBgMDMYnFEWCACsADZnMstTrZhUaVgjQh8CaGoSQEKzfaSr7BDLOvg8XzPcw0AMUMx7lpiQA5S7GCMxgbAZgAVRtGAAwnBkhAtOYlg1fr9RFNItItHrQcVZksgA)